# Cant Integrate Jira in xwiki

Tags: jira, xwiki

XWIKI 11.3 jetty with hsqldb
windows 10 OS and google chrome browser
here i am working with jira…so i created a account in jira.xwiki.org… and i use that same credentials for Global Administration: JIRA in xwiki… but when i follow the method that described in the following address i get some error like 403 https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/JIRA%20Project%20Management%20Application 2

Jira Tasks

Unknow error.

(jira macro failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://jira.xwiki.org/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=(project+%3D+'XWIKI'+and+fixVersion+%3D+'6.4-milestone-1'+and+resolution%3D'unresolved')&field=type&field=key&field=status&field=summary&field=assignee&field=link&os_username=anandhaks& see in log file)

Comment: I just checked the URL you posted and this works for me now (i.e. I get no response code 403). Maybe the server at http://jira.xwiki.org had a problem that now went away. Can you please try again and see if the error is still present?

Comment: Oh, I see from comments on the XWiki forum that this is somehow related to user authentication. Any chance to run the macro without authentication? The page in question should be available without need to log in. If the problem cannot be solved that way, maybe file a bug report against the "JIRA Project Management Application" to use the "JIRA Macro" instead of the "Secure JIRA Macro", as the page for the latter suggests: https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Macro%20Secure%20Jira#HDescription